# copying to usb drive stucks in xubuntu

Tags: linux, usb, file-transfer, xubuntu

I am using a 12.04 64 bit version of xubuntu and whenever i try to copy files from my computer to any usb drive, it starts with a good speed and comes almost to an end very fast but as soon as it reaches and starts showing  "1 second remaining" it just stuck and sits like that for minutes and do nothing, no response at all, and then suddenly the file copy gets completed successfully. So why this problem occurs is anyone having a solution for that?

I have also uploaded the screen at which it get stuck, the screenshot is without the string "1 second remaining" but the same occurs with the string visible on the progress bar. The screenshot is taken when i tried to copy a file of almost 900 mb to my usb drive. The problem doesn't occur when copying small files such as of few kbs or so.

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you use the command line and run `cp foo.avi /media/USBDRIVE`?

Comment: Yes it does that without any problem and took about 40 sec or more to do that.

Comment: Taking 40sec is normal, that's a relatively large file. Does it work if you wait the same amount of time when doing it graphically?

Comment: no it takes more time when doing so graphically

Comment: Yes, but does it _work_? Your question says it gets stuck.

Comment: Yes i said so because it takes unusual amount of time for doing that graphically

Comment: well thankyou for your help, i think it's normal and there is nothing to worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works from the command line, my guess is that it takes pretty much the same amount of time but the GUI is misinterpreting the remaining time so it gets stuck at "one second left".

It is hard to calculate how long a transfer to USB will take because the actual copy speed will vary over time. So your graphical interface thinks it will take 3 minutes because at first it is going very fast, but it is wrong so the countdown stops at -1 second and stays there for a while. If you time the command line and graphical transfers I think you'll find they take the same (or nearly the same) amount of time.

Comment: yup i got it thank u very much for your solution.